# How do I view multiple users groups using sssd?

Tags: linux, rhel, login, ldap, sssd

### SETUP

**OS = RHEL 6.4 Workstation**

System is part of an LDAP domain and was originally configured to authenticate using **nscd**.

All recommended SSSD packages have been installed.

```
[root@sssd_system]#  rpm -qa | grep sssd
sssd-client-1.11.6-30.el6_6.4.x86_64
sssd-common-1.11.6-30.el6_6.4.x86_64
sssd-common-pac-1.11.6-30.el6_6.4.x86_64
sssd-krb5-common-1.11.6-30.el6_6.4.x86_64
sssd-ldap-1.11.6-30.el6_6.4.x86_64
sssd-proxy-1.11.6-30.el6_6.4.x86_64
sssd-tools-1.11.6-30.el6_6.4.x86_64
```

Files which have been created/modified to switch over to **SSSD**:

**/etc/nsswitch.conf**

```
[root@sssd_system]# ls -ld /etc/nsswitch.conf  
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 560 Apr  9 12:07 /etc/nsswitch.conf
```

cat /etc/nsswitch.conf

```
passwd:     files sss  
shadow:     files sss  
group:      files sss  
ethers:     files sss  
services:   files sss  
netgroup:   files sss
```

**/etc/sssd/sssd.conf**

```
[root@sssd_system]# ls -ld /etc/sssd/sssd.conf   
-rw------- 1 root root 971 Apr  9 11:48 /etc/sssd/sssd.conf
```

cat /etc/sssd/sssd.conf

```
[domain/default]  
ldap_schema = rfc2307bis  
ldap_uri = ldap://server1.domain.com,ldap://server2.domian.com  
ldap_search_base = dc=domain,dc=com  
ldap_user_search_base = ou=People,dc=domain,dc=com  
ldap_group_search_base = ou=Group,dc=domain,dc=com  
ldap_group_member = member  
id_provider = ldap  
auth_provider = ldap  
chpass_provider = ldap  
ldap_id_use_start_tls = False  
cache_credentials = True  
ldap_tls_cacertdir = /etc/openldap/cacerts  
ldap_tls_cacert = /etc/openldap/cacerts/certname.pem  
debug_level = 9


[sssd]
domains = default
services = nss,pam,autofs
config_file_version = 2
sbus_timeout = 30
```

***NOTE:*** The **authconfig** command was used to configure this system, so in theory, that means that all the right files were touch with the correct information.

---

### ISSUE 1

<strike>[USERID@sssd_system]# getent passwd USERID

     USERID:*:12345:1002:USER ID:/home/USERID:/bin/bash</strike>

```
[USERID@sssd_system]#  getent group USERGRP  
USERGRP:*:1002:  

[USERID@sssd_system]# groups USERID  
USERID : groups: cannot find name for group ID 1002  
1002
```

**UPDATE:** *This issue turned out do be an error with the **Groups** table within ldap itself; it has been corrected.*

---

### ISSUE 2

```
[USERID@nscd_host]# groups USERID  
USERID: USERGRP USERGRP2 USERGRP3 USERGRP4 USERGRP5  

[USERID@nscd_host]# ssh USERID@sssd_system  
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Workstation release 6.4 (Santiago)  
Last login: Thu Apr  9 11:51:38 2015 from nscd_host  

[USERID@sssd_system]# groups USERID  
USERID: USERGRP
```

---

### QUESTION

***What am I missing?***

I've been researching the dickens for a solution to what is likely a simple configuration error, but haven't been able to pinpoint the exact config file(s).  I've also reference Red Hat's documentation on setting up SSSD in their *Deployment Guide* and found several helpful guides posted out on the web.

And, I've also enabled debug level within **sssd.conf** file, but have not been able to find anything overtly meaningful within the logs ***/var/log*/sssd/*** log file(s) or **/var/log/(message|secure)** either.

Any assistance to what I might be missing would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not using AD, authenticating to a legacy unix/Solaris ldap setup here at the shop, but I'll check out the link you provided; at this point any assistance is welcomed.